# Regex to extract word from a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, match

I am trying to extract the word(s) inside round brackets.

Code:

```
$('.vote').each(function() {
 var vote_count = $('.vote .likedButton').attr('title');
 var split_count = vote_count.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/,"");
 alert(split_count);
});
```

The string I am trying to get-

`Message reputation : 50% (2 votes)`  trying to get 2 votes

The JavaScript Regex I have above is only deleting this line. Am I missing some regex or do I need to use

```
.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/);
```

Can someone explain thank you

Comment: Doesn't need a down vote as it is a simple question. I've had this code working before and some how I am forgetting which to use or what I am doing wrong should I use the asterisk after the ^? Like so ^*

Comment: You're using `replace()` instead of `match()` in your example. Change that and you'll be able to get the text you want with  `alert(split_count[1]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/isabah/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.vote').each(function() {

   var str = $('.likedButton', this).attr('title');
   $(this).prepend( str.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1] );

});
```

Comment: Ahh see I knew I need to .match(), wow completely lost my mind thinking of this.

Comment: @EasyBB not only, take care of descendants `$('.likedButton', this)` means `.likedButton` children of `this (.vote)`

Comment: @roXon: `$(this).find('.likedButton')` is more intuitive.

Comment: @Blender intuitive is what you're used to, in any case heard that `.find()` is a bit more faster, so that's actually a good suggestion you could (@) at EasyBB

Comment: @roXon: "Familiar" is what you're used to. Intuitive means it needs little if any explanation. The context argument is incredibly *unintuitive*.

Comment: well the reason I have $('.vote .likeButton') and not $('.likedButton',this) is because I was debugging I wouldn't .each() in my code lol. I am going to for loop it and take care of everything then. I just wanted to make sure my debugging was done first. Thank you though

Comment: @EasyBB ohh that's good news than, you should be able to move on with your project now ;) Happy coding

Comment: @roXon same to you and I appreciate the help very much so. Some times the rust needs to be dusted off ;)

Comment: @squint you're right, you know, typing code sometimes you don't realize someone could have difficulties to understand, that's why I explained it in my very first comment. Guess there's nothing wrong with it. Thanks for your message tho.